# Making SPARQL FILTER conditional

Tags: sparql

How to make a `FILTER()` conditional? This is the relevant part of my query:

```
SELECT *

WHERE {

 VALUES (?open) {$U2}
 ?URI_OPP CSV:id_opportunita ?ID_OPP.

 OPTIONAL { ?URI_OPP CSV:data_scadenza ?DATA_S }

 FILTER ((NOW() - xsd:datetime(?DATA_S)) > 0) 
}
```

It gets `$U2` as a value for `?open`.  I want to apply the filter if `?open = 1`, and not to apply it in all other cases.

While `IF()` works on the query results, I don't know what to use to switch off parts of the query itself.

Comment: Is it not easier to do this in the client code? I mean, when you also set the value `$U2` in the code, you could also (un)comment the FILTER with `#` if `?open != 1`.

Comment: Otherwise, why not doing `FILTER( (?open != 1) || (((NOW() - xsd:datetime(?DATA_S)) > 0) )` . Only if `?open = 1` the second part of the filter will be executed

Comment: @AKSW the query is controlled at the server side, behind a URL rewrite rule. I haven't thought for the second solution, but this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot! (why don't you put it as an answer so we can "close" this?)

Answer (score 1):

Since the above commented never answered, I will:

```
FILTER(
  (?open != 1) ||
  ((NOW() - xsd:datetime(?DATA_S)) > 0)
)
```